# Get the last value of a column when another has a specific value

Tags: google-sheets

In this great community I always like to learn with what I am discovering, that is why I would like to know if this solution that I have found can be done in a better way.

I have two columns where I am introducing values and I get a value from a column according to the condition of the first one.

I do this with the following google sheets formula:

```
=INDEX(filter(Blockchains!F$2:F,Blockchains!E$2:E=VALUEA),ROWS(filter(Blockchains!F$2:F,Blockchains!E$2:E=VALUEA)),1)
```

Is there a way to make it better?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SORT(E:F, ROW(E:E), ), "where Col2 = 'VALUEA'", ), 1, 1)
```

[image]

better safe than sorry:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SORT(E:F, ROW(E:E), )&"", "where Col2 = 'VALUEA'", ), 1, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your idea but doen't work. The value is in number and don't clasify well the order.

Comment: @LuisMiguelDelgado can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?